# How do I create a Home page for my AWS Amplify web app?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, web-applications, aws-amplify

I'm a bit of a noob trying to create a web application using AWS Amplify. The frameworks I've chosen are JavaScript/React. So far I've created a very basic data model and I've configured log in and sign up. I'm now kind of stuck with what to do next. How do I go about creating a home page for my app? As far as I can tell, the UI library only lets me make 'create' or 'update' forms.

Also, once I've created a Home page, how do I go about viewing the app in my browser?

Any advice would be much appreciated :)

Comment: You'll have to share more details regarding framework, etc but here is a tutorial I've frequently followed: https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/AWS-Amplify-landing-web/

Comment: @johnkhigginson Thanks John, I think the framework I'm using is React? I was under the impression I'd just be able to make some HTML pages but it all seems a lot more complex than that.

Answer (score 0):

I think of AWS Amplify as having 5 parts:

1. The `amplify` cli tool that helps you create/update/delete and
   deploy resources (e.g. database, S3 bucket for storage,
   lambda(s) to run backend code, etc) into your project.
2. The [Amplify Studio](https://docs.amplify.aws/console/) web based admin frontend that does the same, but also has nice GUI to help you model and manage data.
3. [FrontEnd APIs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/q/platform/js/) that make it easier to use some of the backend resources (GraphQL for the DB, Storage APIs for saving user files, Authentication, etc)
4. [Hosting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/welcome.html) (for the front-end website)
5. UI components ([Figma to code](https://docs.amplify.aws/console/uibuilder/figmatocode/) & [UI components](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/getting-started/introduction) you can use in your frontend)

To get going, you can build your front end by following your favorite React tutorial.

Once you have a webpage or webapp working you can host it via Amplify with view or no changes. But to "really" use Amplify, you'll want to add it to your project, then add "amplify managed resources" like a database or S3 bucket.

Follow [this Amplify react tutorial](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/installation/q/integration/react/) to get started.

Basically, make a webapp. Then `amplify init` to in the root directory to add Amplify. Then pull Amplify into your `main.tsx` file:

```
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import awsExports from './aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(awsExports);
```

... and elsewhere in your app you can start using the Amplify UI elements or APIs.

**Edit**
[This AWS video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdfD8WKUA9E) goes from zero to amplify react app that uploads files.